# CSS: How to Control Sidebar Background Color using z-index

Tags: css, colors, z-index

Here is a summary of what I am trying to achieve:

1. I have a wrapper div where the background color is tan.
2. The wrapper div has 2 children.  A sidebar div, and a content div.  Both of these children contain links.
3. The sidebar div needs a background color of grey.

I created a sidebar:before pseudo-element with a z-index of `-1`.  This pseudo-element disappears.  When I changed the z-index to `0` this element was placed on top of the sidebar div and my sidebar information was hidden.

I added some sample code like [these](http://jsfiddle.net/ann_b/PVugn/5/):

---

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="sidebar">
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">sidebar</a></p>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
     <p><a href="www.google.com">content</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

---

```
.wrap {
  position:relative;
  background-color:tan;
}

.sidebar, .sidebar:before {
  width:25%;
}
.sidebar {
  float:left;
  color: #ebeef3;
  font-size: 90%;
}
.sidebar:before {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #5f6673;
}
```

---

This code is based on a [great tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403) that show on columns with equal heights.

Comment: I neglected to mention an important point.  The sidebar and content heights have to be the same, regardless of what each div contains.  That's why the background color has to be set in the pseudo-element, where its' height gets stretched to the wrap div height.

Answer (score 0):

Most developers can just follow the TutsPlus tutorial as is and it will work.  (Link is provided in the question.)  However on Drupal websites the position property for the .l-content div element is sometimes set to relative, and sometimes left at the default.  So we can't use the .content pseudo-element the tutorial uses.  So I changed the css slightly as follows:

```
.wrap:before {
    width:75%;
}

.wrap {
    position:relative;
}

.wrap:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 25%;
    background-color:tan;
}

.sidebar, .sidebar:before {
    width:25%;
}
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    color: #ebeef3;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.sidebar:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #5f6673;
}
```

I added some sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ann_b/PVugn/9/).

I am using Drupal 7 / Omega 4 / SASS / Compass / Ruby.